# $\ker f^k=\operatorname{Im}f^k$ for $k \in \mathbb N$ for nilpotent $f$ $\Rightarrow$ lengths of chains in basis are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, nilpotence

> If $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R ^n$ is a nilpotent linear operator with $\ker f^k=\operatorname{Im}f^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$, then all the chains that are in a chain basis of $f$ have the same length?

If a look at the Jordan Matrix representing $f$, then I am looking for the size of each block and say that they are equal? but what can I conclude from $\ker f^k=Imf^k$ for $k \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: Do you mean $\dim\ker f^k=\dim\text{Im}f^k$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown No, the sub-spaces are equal, nothing was mentioned about their dimensions.

Comment: Does it mean "for **some** integer $k\ge 1$"?

Comment: @A.Γ. Yes, I'll correct it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The condition on kernel/image is basis independent, hence, we can consider $f$ be given in the Jordan form. But then the space is split into a direct sum of invariant subspaces, each being given by a Jordan block, and $\ker f^k=\operatorname{im}f^k$ is equivalent to $\ker J^k=\operatorname{im}J^k$ for each Jordan block $J$. Now for a nilpotent Jordan block of size $m$ it holds
$$
J^k=\begin{bmatrix}0_{(m-k)\times k} & I_{(m-k)\times(m-k)}\\0_{k\times k} & 0_{k\times (m-k)}\end{bmatrix},
$$
and the condition $\ker J^k=\operatorname{im}J^k$ is equivalent to $k=m-k$, hence, $m=2k$. Since this is true for any Jordan block, they must have the same size. The size of a block is the length of a corresponding chain, so all the chains have the same length.

Comment: How can one's reason that $\text{Im}J^k = \text{Ker}J^k$? Thanks

Comment: @X4J Because the space is split into a direct product of invariant subspaces. For example,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}A & 0\\0 & B\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
Ax=0,\ By=0.
$$
Similarly
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}A & 0\\0 & B\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\end{bmatrix}
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad x=Au,\ y=Bv.
$$